Bash : How to create a Bash script that has the ability to update itself?
Goal : Create a bash script that can update itself
Example
./my-script.sh 
 $ Hello world

Then when supplied with argument to update itself
./my-script.sh --update

./my-script.sh
$ Hello World Updated!

Problem : Unable to update script while loaded in memory
Things I've tried
#!/bin/bash

function update {
 
 urlOfUpdatedVersion="..."
 existingScriptLocation = "..."
 myLocalPath="..."

 wget $urlOfUpdatedVersion > $myLocalPath/my-script.sh

 mv myLocalPath/my-script.sh $existingScriptLocation
}

if [[ "$1" == "--update" ]]; then
 update
fi

echo "Hello World"

For sake of simplicity assume the updated script that gets pull down from the 'wget' is the exact same but with the following echo update
echo "Hello World Updated"


One way to solve would be to have a wrapper script that will check the version of the actual internal script and update it and/or execute it.

What's wrong with the code you wrote? The next time you run the script, you'll get the updated version.

would you have a subsequent exec or eval command call the same script again?

If you want to make it run the new version immediately, you'll need to re-execute it. Put exec "$existingScriptLocation" at the end of the update function.

BTW, remember to put all your variables in quotes.

It is unclear what your problem is. If the script replaces the file containing itself, the new version will run the next time you run it, which seems to be exactly what you want.

the script fails, unable to replace the existing script that is currently running

Sound like an xy problem, why would you want to do this instead of reading your change from another place (db,json,...)?

sounds like your not reading the question then 'Unable to update script while loaded in memory'. Someone answered the question below btw. Thanks

Updating a script while its running can be hard because the script is already loaded in memory, so it can be difficult to modify it directly. But you can use a turnaround for this.

First: Create a temporary script to handle the update
Second: Download the new version of the script
Third: Replace the original script with the new version
Finally: You run the new updated script

Here is an example of how I would apply this :
#!/bin/bash

function update {
    urlOfUpdatedVersion="https://example.com/path/to/updated-script.sh"
    existingScriptLocation="$(realpath "$0")"
    tempScriptLocation="/tmp/my-script.sh"

    # Download the updated version to a temporary location
    wget -q -O "$tempScriptLocation" "$urlOfUpdatedVersion"

    # Replace the current script with the updated version
    if [[ -f "$tempScriptLocation" ]]; then
        mv "$tempScriptLocation" "$existingScriptLocation"
        chmod +x "$existingScriptLocation"
        echo "Script updated successfully."

        # Optionally, you can run the updated script
        exec "$existingScriptLocation"
    else
        echo "Failed to download the updated script."
        exit 1
    fi
}

if [[ "$1" == "--update" ]]; then
    update
    exit 0
fi

echo "Hello World"


This isn't trivial. bash will get confused when the script changes while it's being executed. This can lead to commands being skipped or executed twice.
To avoid this, you need a wrapper script which does the updating and then calls the "real" script passing all arguments using "$@" (expands to all arguments preserving quotes).
The question is then how do you update the wrapper script? This can be tricky. I would go for this approach:

Keep the update code into another script (so you have three scripts: wrapper, update and worker).
If you need to update the update-script, then download it under temporary name using the original update-script. In the wrapper, you then have to check whether the temporary update-script exists and rename it before doing anything else.

This way, the wrapper is so small that it should never need any changes. It should basically look like this:
basedir="$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"

# Replace update.sh if there is a new version
if [[ -e "$basedir/new-update.sh" ]]; then
    mv "$basedir/new-update.sh" "$basedir/update.sh" || exit 1
fi

if [[ "$1" == "--update" ]]; then
    shift # get rid of update parameter
    $basedir/update.sh || exit 1
fi

# Do the work; if we get here, update.sh has finished.
$basedir/worker.sh "$@" || exit 1


Thank you for well developed and constructive response Aaron! Much appreciated!
